# is there any styleguide for building ionic app like johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I've just started using learning ionic for build a hybrid web app for mobile devices but i just what style guide on how to build a ionic web app.

is there any styleguide for building ionic app like johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Comment: https://github.com/simian-lab/ionic-styleguide

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/

Answer (score 1):

I think that there isn't such a thing. But because `Ionic` is just a framework on top of `AngularJS`, you just have to follow John Papa's Angular Style Guide. 
But you will need to include manually all the `.js` in your `index.html`.

That's can be messy because of Angular's dependency injection system.
The solution might be to use a a build automation like `Gulp` or `Grunt` to take care of that. 
This GitHub [repo](https://github.com/flavordaaave/ionic-better-structure) might be interesting for you.